# Entity Framework .net: Do i need to call update after saveChangesAsync

Tags: database, entity-framework, savechanges

If I have fetch data from database using FindAsync and set the properties after i fetch.  Later i saved using SaveChangesAsync. After the SaveChangeAsync, I modify the data again. Do I call the SaveChangesAsync again or Update.

```
var data = await db.FindAsync(..) 
data.property = "test"
await db.SaveChangeAsync()
data.property = "test1"
db.SaveChangeAsync or db.Update(data) then db.SaveChangeAsync
```

Which should I call at the end.

Comment: The changes will be written to the persistence only on calling SaveChanges...db.Update will notify your context to update that property in-memory...in your case, the context is already tracking the changes (you will need to call AsNoTracking() if you wish to not let the context track changes)..so I guess calling Update explicitly won't be necessary...

Comment: What @gkb is saying is partly true. db.Update() does attach its argument to the context and set its state to modified, with that alone there is nothing written to the database, the changes are communicated at the SaveChanges() call. Since data is tracked by the context, its state will be modified if the context's AutoDetectChanges configuration property is true, otherwise you'll have to call db.Update() before the SaveChanges() call. AsNoTracking() on the other hand will not mean that the context won't track changes - it just won't track this specific object (i.e. disconnected scenario)